# How can I get "canonical" name of the text encoding of current Atom active editor?

Tags: atom-editor

I have recently adding a fix for [atom-script package](https://github.com/atom-community/atom-script/) to resolve garbled text output in compile&run Java code in non-English Windows environment. ([Issue #1166](https://github.com/atom-community/atom-script/issues/1166), [PR #2471](https://github.com/atom-community/atom-script/pull/2471))

After this, now in release [script package 3.32.1](https://github.com/atom-community/atom-script/releases/tag/v3.32.1), javac has options `-J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` and `-encoding UTF-8` both. (diff is [here](https://github.com/atom-community/atom-script/commit/e730f08d2cc8954a6562fef4e905776585074b63)) I have just realized that it is better to provide actual encoding of the current active editor which holds the target source code for `-encoding` option. After some research, I have learnt that the encoding can be acquired by

```js
atom.workspace.getActiveTextEditor().getEncoding()
```

but, after I have tested in Japanese edition Windows, it returns `shiftjis` and this is not valid encoding name for javac command line option. (It should be `MS932`, `SJIS` or something similar.) I have no idea where I can get this type of encoding names without writing large conversion table for all possible encoding names. Is there any good utility for such purpose?

EDIT:
For demonstrating what I have supposed to do, I have created branch on my fork. Diff is [here](https://github.com/mhatano/atom-script/commit/1643ea0e8f9d47a15bece4b1d3ed84c5bbf2ddb5).

Getting current source code editor encoding by

```js
  const fileEncoding = getJavaTextEncodingName(atom.workspace.getActiveTextEditor().getEncoding())
```

and pass it to javac via

```js
  const cmd = `javac -encoding ${fileEncoding} -J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xlint -sourcepath '${sourcePath}' -d '${tempFolder}' '${filepath}' && java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -cp '${tempFolder}' ${classPackages}${className}`
```

And, function "getJavaTextEncodingName()" is the core of the question.

```js
function getJavaTextEncodingName(atomTextEncodingName) {
  switch (atomTextEncodingName) {
    case "shiftjis" :
      return "MS932"
  }
  return "UTF-8"
}
```

It is obvious that this is converting "shiftjis" to "MS932" but, it is not so beautiful if we implement all possible encoding name conversions here, so I am seeking better alternative.

Comment: Does this help? https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-arduino/commit/00d3fefcead1a95ec1b1ffbb32abc0f1b0a47a82

Comment: @idleberg Thanks, these code is really good example for me to update my knowledge about electron programming. Unfortunately this does not help solving my problem directly, still it is very very useful.